# How to log user out due to inactivity

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

Pure, server-side PHP. Every time a user submits a form, I update a 'last activity' time in the database.

I want to make a periodic check and force logout inactive users to free up licenses.

How would I do that? Should I also store the session Id in the database and then destroy the session? That would free up a license for another user and when the first finally submits another form I can check at the top of each form action file if the session still exists and redirect the user to the login page if necessary.

Would that work? is it the 'best' way? Any example code?

---

Update: I am polling because I need to know when the user timesout in order to update the database.

Comment: Sessions expire automatically in php, and you can set the session max lifetime.

Comment: +1 oops, I forgot to mention that I need to update the database to show user logged out, which is why I am polling. I have updated the question

Comment: p.s how to set the session max lifetime? I suspect that I need to set it very high.

Comment: `ini_set(‘session.gc_maxlifetime’ ?)` or update the php.ini itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is more difficult than it seems on the surface.

You need to consider the session behavior at three different levels:

- PHP
- database
- browser

**PHP**

For PHP, you'll need to set the session timeout to whatever you limit is. Here's some example code from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php):

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('private');
/* set the cache expire to 30 minutes */
session_cache_expire(30);    
session_start();
?>
```

**Database**

Sounds like you need to keep track of how many sessions are active so you can enforce your license. Since  you're in PHP, you'll need to do this at the database level. Each request could write a "last request time" for the user (`UPDATE users SET last_access=NOW() WHERE user_id=?`), and then you can surmise that active sessions are the ones within the last 30 minutes.

Rather than "last access time", you can try to keep track of the active sessions, again in the database. I'm not exactly sure how this is best done in PHP. I think you can patch into the PHP's session deletion code. I believe it's possible to have it call a function when a session expires, but I haven't done this.

**Browser**

Javascript polling can be used, but is not necessary, as long as you have a server side timeout. Consider cases where the user turns off Javascript, or you have some Javascript error that causes script to stop running.

We have a very Ajax intensive site, so Javascript is important. A timeout might be discovered when the user does something as innocuous as open a panel on a page. [I wrote up my recent experience here.](http://blog.ndpsoftware.com/2011/03/friendlier-session-timeouts-20.html)

Answer (score 5):

With each login, you need to keep track of the Session Start Time, which can be done like this:

```
$_SESSION['SessionStartTime'] = time();
```

With each user request to perform any operation, you need to run this script to monitor inactivity.

```
<?php
session_start();
$TimeOutMinutes = 15; // This is your TimeOut period in minutes
$LogOff_URL = "login.php"; // If timed out, it will be redirected to this page

$TimeOutSeconds = $TimeOutMinutes * 60; // TimeOut in Seconds
if (isset($_SESSION['SessionStartTime'])) {
    $InActiveTime = time() - $_SESSION['SessionStartTime'];
    if ($InActiveTime >= $TimeOutSeconds) {
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: $LogOff_URL");
    }
}
$_SESSION['SessionStartTime'] = time();
?>
```

Comment: Will the script run if the user has closed he browser? If not, which I dont think it should, what can you fall back on so that e.g I can update the database?

Comment: There is a spelling mistake in the variable "InactiveTime. In line 8 it is spelled "InactiveTime" and in Line 9 it is "InActiveTime". Thanks for the example it was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this purely using JavaScript. Start an count down timer. Then wait for activity and reset this timer. If there is no activity and timer goes off, you can call your logoff sequence.

for Example :

```
<body onmousemove="reset_interval()" onclick="reset_interval()" onkeypress="reset_interval()" onscroll="reset_interval()">


<script type="text/javascript">
function set_interval(){
  //the interval 'timer' is set as soon as the page loads
  timer=setInterval("auto_logout()",10000);
  // the figure '10000' above indicates how many milliseconds the timer be set to.
  //Eg: to set it to 5 mins, calculate 5min= 5x60=300 sec = 300,000 millisec.So set it to 3000000
}

function reset_interval(){
  //resets the timer. The timer is reset on each of the below events:
  // 1. mousemove   2. mouseclick   3. key press 4. scroliing
  //first step: clear the existing timer
  clearInterval(timer);
  //second step: implement the timer again
  timer=setInterval("auto_logout()",10000);
  ..completed the reset of the timer
}

function auto_logout(){
  //this function will redirect the user to the logout script
  window.location="your_logout_script_location_here";
}
</script>
```

Hope that helps.

PS: Reference from: http://www.w3hobbyist.com/web-designing/auto-logout-after-some-time-of-inactivity-with-javascript/

Comment: sorry, nut it is pure server-side PHP

Comment: Thanks, This won't work if a user opens multiple windows on the same site. Eg, if a user opens one window then opens another one in 10 minutes later. The first window would redirect to logout.php to kill the user's session which shouldn't, because the user is still in active mode within the past 15 minutes.

Comment: This approach could work if the auto_logout function was making a fetch request to a PHP script which was in charge of handling the session, so based on the response from the PHP script the JavaScript function will log out a user.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to make a periodic check and
>   force logout inactive users to free up
>   licenses

I assume you meant..  When a session has (should have) expired, you need to 'do something' to free a license, and you want it controlled server-side.

session.gc_maxlifetime hurts here because PHP does not send notification when it destroys a session.

You need a cron job to scan the PHP session folder for sessions whose atime has exceeded your timeout and release their license (and also delete the session). A beginning for such a script is

cd /path/to/sessions; find -cmin +24 | xargs rm

which was taken from the bottom of 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime
You will replace the *xargs rm* with something more useful to you.

Comment: +1 Yes, I am definitely thinking along those lines. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

All these solutions are interesting and work well.

But: What if you are in a frame-based content window?

Then there are two options:

1. Before logging out or calling the logout script, the frame-based top of the page must be reached (can be done using a JavaScript command "unnestling" the depth of the current position within the frame)
2. Alternatively, a frame buster oder frame killer script can be invoked to reset to the top's position such as

`<style> html{display : none ; } </style>`
`<script>`
`if( self == top ) {`
`document.documentElement.style.display = 'block' ;`
`} else {`
`top.location = self.location ;`
`}`
`</script>`

(c. o. WikiPedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller)

More about frame busters and frame killers can be read from various sources by a simple Internet search for "framebuster" or "framekiller".

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version based directly on the answer by RKh.

This version will re-set the timer IF the session hasn't timed out yet. So you can paste this whole block right underneath your session_start() and you don't have to call it separately every time a user makes a request to perform an action.

```
/* Control Session Timeout */
if (!isset($_SESSION['LastActivity'])) {
$_SESSION['LastActivity'] = time();
}
//Set Timeout Window in Minutes
$TimeOutMinutes = 5;
//TimeOut in Seconds
$TimeOutSeconds = $TimeOutMinutes * 60; 

if (isset($_SESSION['LastActivity'])) {
    $InactiveTime = time() - $_SESSION['LastActivity'];
        //If Inactive Time more than timeout value log the user out
        if ($InactiveTime >= $TimeOutSeconds) {
            session_destroy();
            header("Location: $baseURL");
        }
        //If Inactive Time less than timeout reset the last activity to current time
        elseif ($InactiveTime < $TimeOutSeconds) {
            $_SESSION['LastActivity'] = time();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I got this simple solution using jQuery.

```
var idleTime = 0;
var start = new Date();
var end;

// if mousemove, a keypressed or a mouse click events fired
$(document).on('mousemove keydown click', function() {
    end = new Date();
    idleTime = (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) /1000;
    // 30 seconds of idle time
    if ( idleTime > 30 ) {
        // logout/endsession code here 
        //window.location.href="logout.php";
    }
});
```

Best Regards.